# PHP - connect to switch and get its config data

Tags: php, ssh, telnet, fsockopen

I need to connect to (3Com) switch (via SSH and Telnet) on server and get its configuration data with PHP code.
I'm already connecting to the switch, now I just don't know how to get its configuration data into database.

My current code:

```
<?php
    $auth=base64_encode("username:password");
    $header="GET /pa2/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
    $header.="Accept: text/html\r\n";
    $header.="Authorization: Basic $auth\r\n";

    $fp = fsockopen ("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 23, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
    } else {
        //missing code
    }
?>
```

Can you please help me

Comment: You're missing a quote at the end of the IP address in the line beginning with `$fp`. Copy and paste error?

Comment: I deleted it by accident when I was changing the IP. I have no error I just don't know commands to get configuration data from switch I'm connected to.

Comment: I don't know enough about the switch to help. Does 3com publish something?

Answer (score 2):

```
$auth=base64_encode("username:password");
$header="GET /pa2/ HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n";
$header.="Accept: text/html\r\n";
$header.="Authorization: Basic $auth\r\n";
```

That's not doing anything in your code.

None-the-less rather than trying to implement your own telnet or SSH client I'd just re-use one. [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/) is a pretty popular SSH client. I'd try that. Here's an example of it's use:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Comment: okay, thanks. But how can I get now the configuration data of this switch?